# Jetpack Compose: Text remains black even when the theme is dark

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The text in the app still remains black even if the theme is set to dark and background is dark. Just take a look at the code and screenshots below.

**Theme.kt** (here, in `DarkColorPalette`, I set `onSurface` and `onBackground` to `Color.White` but it doesn't help)

```kotlin
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = PastelGreen,
    secondary = PastelGreenTransparent,
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = PastelGreen,
    onBackground = Color.White,
    onSurface = Color.White
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = PastelGreen,
    secondary = PastelGreenTransparent,
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = PastelGreen,
)

@Composable
fun EschoolTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColorPalette else LightColorPalette,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

**Type.kt**

```kotlin
val manropeFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.light, FontWeight.Light),
    Font(R.font.regular, FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(R.font.medium, FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.bold, FontWeight.Bold),
    Font(R.font.extra_bold, FontWeight.ExtraBold),
    Font(R.font.extra_light, FontWeight.ExtraLight),
    Font(R.font.semi_bold, FontWeight.SemiBold),
)

val typography =
    Typography(
        defaultFontFamily = manropeFamily,
        h5 = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, fontSize = 23.sp,),
        button = TextStyle(letterSpacing = 0.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
    )
```

**Code of the screen** (don't take care about Russian texts)

```
@Composable
fun Onboarding() {
    EschoolTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(20.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon),
                    contentDescription = "Иконка приложения со смайлом, смотрящим через монокль",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        .size(100.dp)
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
                Text(
                    "Добро пожаловать в eschool!",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(
                        Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    )
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            }
            Text(
                "Здесь ты можешь быстро делиться домашкой и расписанием со своими одноклассниками без всяких мессенжджеров. Используй это приложение как школьный дневник, в который ты обычно записываешь д/з и расписание. Всё, что ты записываешь сюда, будет сразу видно и твоим одноклассникам. Тебе больше не придётся ждать ответа от твоих одноклассников в мессенджерах или наоборот отвечать им. Чтобы начать пользоваться приложением, надо войти в аккаунт.",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            LargeButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, secondary = true) {
                Text("У меня уже есть аккаунт")
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            LargeButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text("Я тут в первый раз")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshots**

| Dark theme | Light theme |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Dark theme screenshot] | [image] |

If you need more code, ask me, I'll provide it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The color in the `Text` is defined by the `color` parameter or applying a `TextStyle`. The default value is [**`Color.Unspecified`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color.Companion#Unspecified()).
If color = `Color.Unspecified` and style has no color set, this will be [**`LocalContentColor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#LocalContentColor()) which provides a default [**`Color.Black`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color.Companion#Black())  color if not specified.

You have different options:

- You can add as parent container a **`Surface`**. In this case it will be used the `Colors.onSurface` specified in your theme.

```
    Surface(){
      Column(){
        Text(){...}
      }
    }
```

- Use the **`color`** parameter in the `Text` composable
- Use the **`style`** parameter:

```
Text(style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(color = Red)){...}
```

- Use a custom **`LocalContentColor`** to override the default `Black` color

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides MaterialTheme.colors.xxx) {
      Text()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping the content with `Surface` helped me!

Comment: Ran into this issue today and figured out using Surface was the best way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can specify `Text` color with using `color` or using `style` values.

When there's no value specified for both of these, `Text` on compose uses `LocalContentColor` value, which is default to `Black` and doesn't depend on the theme

If you wanna change default text color for the whole app, the best solution is to override this value right after introducing your theme:

```
setContent {
    YourTheme {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalContentColor provides MaterialTheme.colors.onSecondary // replace this with needed color from your pallete
        ) {
            Content()
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can override this value again using `CompositionLocalProvider` to any part of your app

Answer (score 2):

You can specify text styles in your app's theme like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = DarkColors,
        typography = Typography(body1 = TextStyle(color = Color.White), button = TextStyle(color = Color.Black)),
        content = content
    )
}
```

Then wrap your content in MyTheme:

```
MyTheme {
    AppContent()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom text composable:

```
@Composable
fun DayNightText(
text: String,
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
color: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface, // Change default color here
fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
softWrap: Boolean = true,
maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    Text(
    text = text,
    modifier = modifier,
    color = color,
    fontSize = fontSize,
    fontStyle = fontStyle,
    fontWeight = fontWeight,
    fontFamily = fontFamily,
    letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
    textDecoration = textDecoration,
    textAlign = textAlign,
    lineHeight = lineHeight,
    overflow = overflow,
    softWrap = softWrap,
    maxLines = maxLines,
    onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
    style = style)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface` color for your `Text` color parameter instead of wrapping `Text` with the `Surface` to get absolutely the same `onSurface` color.

```
YourAppTheme(
    darkTheme = true
) {
    Text(
        text = "text with dark theme color",
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
    )
}
```