# Jetpack Compose: Text remains black when the theme is dark despite using approved solution from analogous question

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There is an analogous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769263/jetpack-compose-text-remains-black-even-when-the-theme-is-dark) to mine already on StackOverflow. It has a comprehensive, accepted answer that I thought would help me in what seems like a trivial problem.

I have a composable consisting of a `Text` composable. It is called `PickerLabel` as it is a part of a larger picker component:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun PickerLabel(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        fontSize = 64.sp,
        modifier = modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { }
            }
    )
}
```

It is used like this (it feels like nothing in its `modifier` can be impacting the text color):

```kotlin
PickerLabel(
    text = \* stringText *\,
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .alpha(\* stringText *\)
)
```

One last useful thing to see from my code would be the `Theme.kt`:

```
private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Jacarta,
    primaryVariant = BlueZodiac,
    secondary = ButterflyBush,
    secondaryVariant = Victoria,
    onPrimary = White,
    onSecondary = White,
    onSurface = White
)

private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Jacarta,
    primaryVariant = BlueZodiac,
    secondary = ButterflyBush,
    secondaryVariant = Victoria,
    onPrimary = White,
    onSecondary = White,
    onSurface = White
)

@Composable
fun AppTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalSpace provides Space()) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColorPalette else LightColorPalette,
            typography = Typography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

With that setup in dark mode the `PickerLabel` is composed as such:

[image]

while it should look like this (it looks like this only in light mode):

[image]

Now, according to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68770041/14037302) to the previously mentioned question, I tried the following:

1. Adding a `Surface` as a parent container (the `onSurface` color was specified as `White` in `Theme.kt`):

```kotlin
setContent {
    AppTheme {
        Surface {
            ScreenContent()
        }
    }
}
```

2. Using the `color` parameter in the `Text` composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun PickerLabel(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        color = White,
        fontSize = 64.sp,
        modifier = modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { }
            }
    )
}
```

3. Using the `style` parameter in the `Text` composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun PickerLabel(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(color = White),
        fontSize = 64.sp,
        modifier = modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { }
            }
    )
}
```

4. Using a custom `LocalContentColor` to override the default `Black` color:

```kotlin
setContent {
    AppTheme {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalContentColor provides White
        ) {
            ScreenContent()
        }
    }
}
```

**NONE** of these solutions worked for me - each time I've tried them the `Text` color remained black no matter what.

Maybe there is a different factor deciding about the `Text` color that the mentioned answers didn't recognize. Or maybe I've made a mistake that can be spotted here in my code. Either way, if You have the slightest idea about what might be going on, please help.

**Edit:** changed the `Theme.kt` to include the check for system theme, to decide which color palette to use.

Comment: you build your color palette using `lightColors` but specify a dark theme, could you first try to correctly use `darkColors` instead?

Comment: @AdrianK Yes, I have tried exactly that and updated the question with the code I used now. I've tried the four solutions again - none of them worked... again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue. The solution is something I would've never thought would make sense.

No wrapping in `Surface` nor specifying some `color` parameters - the solution (at least in my, pretty specific, case) was to:

1. Unwrap the `Text` composable from the `PickerLabel`,
2. Set the `fontSize` to `63.8.sp` (that's right - `63.9.sp` was already too much and made the text black).

With those two (quite surprising and weird) steps the `Text` is composed in `White` color. No additional code was changed besides what I've said:

```kotlin
Text(
    text = /* stringText */,
    fontSize = 63.8.sp,
    modifier = modifier
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .alpha(/* floatAlpha */)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures { }
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a different solution :D Using MaterialTheme

```
**Method**
@Composable
private fun PickerLabel(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
//you can use body1, h5, h4, caption etc for your typography
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption.copy(fontSize = 64.sp),
        modifier = modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { }
        }
    )
}


**Preview**
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        Surface {
            Column {
                PickerLabel("12:53")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
@Composable
fun DefaultDarkPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        Surface {
            Column {
                PickerLabel("12:53")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result here :D **
[Dark and light mode text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuHb9.png)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately, that wasn't the case :(